# How do I properly externalize spring-boot kafka-streams configuration in a properties file?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm trying to externalize the configuration of a spring-kafka application that I currently have written in Java code. 
Should I be putting the `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` values into `spring.kafka.streams.properties`, or will they be properly configured if I provide them through`spring.kafka.producer` and `spring.kafka.consumer`?

So far, it appears that I am supposed to get all of my configuration into a bean of type `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` in order to configure my kafka-streams app. Currently, I am doing that by setting `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` values directly in code.

When I externalize this configuration, it appears that setting the property values from `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` in the `application.properties` file does not correlate with them being in the `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` created by spring-boot (I confirmed this by autowiring the configuration somewhere and taking a look at it).

If I instead provide the `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` values through `spring.kafka.streams.properties` they show up in the `KafkaStreamsConfiguration`.

Here is my old Java configuration:

```java
@Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, commitInterval);
        props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
        props.put("replication.factor", replicationFactor);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/var/lib/kafka-streams");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_CLEANUP_DELAY_MS_CONFIG, "600000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }
```

this ends up with `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` values not being in the `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` at runtime:

```
spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.streams.properties.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.kafka.streams.application-id=<application_id>
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=<group_id> #this won't show up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration
spring.kafka.streams.replication-factor=1
spring.kafka.streams.properties.commit.interval.ms=100
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.deserialization.exception.handler=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
spring.kafka.producer.compression-type=lz4 #this won't show up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration
spring.kafka.streams.properties.state.dir=/var/lib/kafka-streams
spring.kafka.streams.properties.state.cleanup.delay.ms=600000
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest #this won't show up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration
spring.kafka.streams.properties.timestamp.extractor=org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.WallclockTimestampExtractor
```

This, however, does result in `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` having the values as expected:

```
spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.streams.properties.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.kafka.streams.application-id=<application_id>
spring.kafka.streams.properties.group-id=<group_id> #this shows up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration
spring.kafka.streams.replication-factor=1
spring.kafka.streams.properties.commit.interval.ms=100
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.deserialization.exception.handler=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
spring.kafka.streams.properties.compression-type=lz4 #this shows up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration
spring.kafka.streams.properties.state.dir=/var/lib/kafka-streams
spring.kafka.streams.properties.state.cleanup.delay.ms=600000
spring.kafka.streams.properties.auto-offset-reset=latest #this shows up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration
spring.kafka.streams.properties.timestamp.extractor=org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.WallclockTimestampExtractor
```

I was expecting the `ProducerConfig` and `ConsumerConfig` values to propagate to the `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` when being set through `spring.kafka.producer` and `spring.kafka.consumer` respectively. Especially since I get Intellisense in IntelliJ for the Producer and Consumer configs in `application.properties`.

That said, do I need to make sure I'm setting those through `spring.kafka.streams.properties` in order for the app to be properly configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=<group_id> #this won't show up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration`

Streams sets the `group.id` to the `application.id` property.

> public static final String APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG = "application.id";
>
> private static final String APPLICATION_ID_DOC = "An identifier for the stream processing application. Must be unique within the Kafka cluster. It is used as 1) the default client-id prefix, 2) the group-id for membership management, 3) the changelog topic prefix.";

See `KafkaProperties`.

`streams`, `producer` and `consumer` properties are distinct and unrelated.

> `spring.kafka.producer.compression-type=lz4 #this won't show up in KafkaStreamsConfiguration`

`compression-type` is not exposed as a first class boot property for streams. You can set it using

```
spring.kafka.streams.properties.compression.type=gzip
```

Comment: you mentioned compression-type is not exposed as first class boot property for streams, how do I know what are all the first class boot properties for kafka streams ? is there a list in any documentation ?

Comment: See the Boot documentation; here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers and here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties