# Spring Boot Kafka StreamsConfig or ConsumerConfig from application.yaml not applying

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a very simple spring boot project with a KTable and I want to customize my configuration in application.yml, but the config seems to not be applied. This is my configuration file application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}
    streams:
      application-id: ${APPLICATION_ID:train-builder-processor}
      buffered-records-per-partition: 50

    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      max-poll-records: ${MAX_POLL_RECORDS:50}
      max-poll-interval-ms: ${KAFKA_CONSUMER_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS:1000}
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages:
                - com.example.kafkastream
```

However, when starting the application the log outputs the following:

```
2022-03-03 08:20:06.992  INFO 32989 --- [           main] s.r.s.m.t.TrainBuilderApplication        : Starting TrainBuilderApplication using Java 16.0.2 on MAPFVFG90ZQQ05P with PID 32989 (/Users/xxx/dev/train-builder-processor/target/classes started by xxx in /Users/xxx/dev/train-builder-processor)
2022-03-03 08:20:06.995 DEBUG 32989 --- [           main] s.r.s.m.t.TrainBuilderApplication        : Running with Spring Boot v2.6.3, Spring v5.3.15
2022-03-03 08:20:06.995  INFO 32989 --- [           main] s.r.s.m.t.TrainBuilderApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-03 08:20:08.856  INFO 32989 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig   : StreamsConfig values: 
    acceptable.recovery.lag = 10000
    application.id = test.train-builder-processor
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
... (a bunch of other configs)
```

ConsumerConfig:

```
...
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1000
...
```

Below is the simple application class I'm using:

```
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
@SpringBootApplication
public class TrainBuilderApplication {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private TrainIdMapper trainIdMapper;

    @Autowired
    private TrainBuilder trainBuilder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TrainBuilderApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public KTable<String, Train> trainTable(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
        return kStreamBuilder
                .stream(Pattern.compile(sourceTopicsPattern), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), myJsonSerde))
                .map(trainIdMapper)
                .filter((key, value) -> key != null)
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), mySerde))
                .aggregate(() -> null, trainBuilder, trainStore);
    }
}
```

The values from my application.yml seems to be ignored. What could be the cause of this? What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think they are ignored? The log you states shows `max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1000
`  and in your configuration you have `max-poll-records: ${MAX_POLL_RECORDS:50}`
      `max-poll-interval-ms: ${KAFKA_CONSUMER_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS:1000}`    Therefore you probably have set a variable somewhere called `MAX_POLL_RECORDS` and `KAFKA_CONSUMER_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS` and taking those?  Otherwise it would default to 50 and 1000.

Comment: @SMA yes, I have tried setting those environment variables without success. I have also tried not having them so it should use the defaults but also without success. Also, the `buffered.records.per.partition` should be 50 according to my config.

Comment: Try to remove that extra blank line before consumer and see if that makes a difference.  Otherwise I would try and see if it respects any other configuration from (consumer) or not, or if your problem only lies with those 2 settings.

Comment: @SMA That didn't work either unfortunately. I also tried setting `auto-offset-reset: latest` but I still see `auto.offset.reset = earliest` in the logs. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out with the help of [How do I properly externalize spring-boot kafka-streams configuration in a properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572044/how-do-i-properly-externalize-spring-boot-kafka-streams-configuration-in-a-prope).

Apparently, `consumer` and `producer` configs are completely separated from `streams` config when using a KStream. To set specific properties for the *consumer of the kafka stream* one must use "additional properties" like so:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,localhost:9092}
    streams:
      application-id: ${APPLICATION_ID:train-builder-processor}
      cache-max-size-buffering: 1048576
      cleanup.on-shutdown: ${CLEANUP_ON_SHUTDOWN:false}
      properties:
        max:
          poll:
            records: 50
```

which was a bit unintuitive, but it works. Hope this can help someone in the future!